# How can we fetch mail from Inbox, sent folder using POP3 in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pop3

I am using **CFNetwork** to connect to my **POP3** account on **Yahoo**.
I've written the code of connection and authentication which is running perfectly.
I have used **CFStream** to read the POP3 server response.

My question is, how can I access the specific folder like **Inbox**, **sent folder** or **delete** folder of my yahoo account using **POP3 command**.
I have to read the mails from the folder and show the list in the specific folder at local IPhone.

kindly help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I m also working on this kind of project Need your help in this.Could you just provide me a sample code through which i can fetch mails from any pop3/smtp mail accounts? like gmail,yahoomail etc. Thanks

Comment: sharing source code is not possible through this media. You can use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost function to connect to the server then open the read and write stream and read the response in (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode method. Later you have to send all the request one by one to the server and read it response accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POP3 protocol is documented in RFC 1939 - [Post Office Protocol](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html).  It does not support the concept of folders.

In fact they mention in section 8:

> Of course the other capabilities of IMAP, such as polling an existing connection for newly arrived
>      messages and supporting multiple folders on the server, are not
>      present in POP3.

IMAP on the other hand does, and is likely what you are looking for. It is well documented in http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html  The command in IMAP to choose a folder is called 'SELECT.'  The protocol looks like this:

> ```
>            C: A142 SELECT INBOX
>            S: * 172 EXISTS
>            S: * 1 RECENT
>            S: * OK [UNSEEN 12] Message 12 is first unseen
>            S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 3857529045] UIDs valid
>            S: * OK [UIDNEXT 4392] Predicted next UID
>            S: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
>            S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \*)] Limited
>            S: A142 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
> ```

If you are doing this as an intelectual exercise, you are going to need to rewrite your networking code to implement IMAP instead of POP.  However if you are doing this as part of a commericial endevaur, I would recommend against writing an email client from scratch -- it is a solved problem with lots of freely avaiable source out there.  You might want to look at the [UW-IMAP toolkit](http://www.washington.edu/imap/), a free C Library  or [VMIME](http://www.vmime.org/) A C++ Library.  Both should be able to work on the iOS platform without too much hassle.

Comment: I need to connect to POP3 server only and hence I can not use IMAP. So I have to rely on one folder only.